# Railo web.cfm showing IIS 404

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I recently did a full 64 bit install of Railo on my Windows 8.1 machine hooking it up to IIS.  The code for the site is in a location outside the c:\railo directory and when I boot it up it did put the WEB-INF folder in the application root like it was supposed to.  When I start the Railo server from the command prompt I am seeing the correct path to the WEB-INF\railo folder for that web context in the start up.  So the code runs and all is good except that I can't get into the admins with IIS throwing a 404.  Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but not related to ColdFusion. should be untagged.

Comment: Anit, I did that because much of the CFML community uses both engines and could possibly provide some assistance.  So if you don't mind I'm going to leave it as it is since both communities are so small these days.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about Railo. Never worked. But probably, if the location is outside the directory, then you need a virtual mapping sort of thing.

Comment: Please provide the URL you are trying to use.  Also, do you have any rewrites enabled?  Jordan's "answer" below will help you rule out an issue with your web server, but from my understanding you SHOULD still be able to hit the web or server administrator from IIS/Apache, you just need to provide us more information about your setup and what you've tried.

Comment: This should've been raised on Server Fault. And - as Anit points out - nothing to do with ColdFusion. ColdFusion ppl are not going to be able to answer a question on Railo Server config. You're actually better off asking this on the Railo Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/railo), as not much of the Railo community use S/O as far as I can tell. Their engineers certainly don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bypass IIS and hit tomcat directly. IE, from the local machine:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.cfm
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/railo-context/admin/server.cfm
```